# Exception Value comparing datetime

Tags: python, django, datetime

My models.py relevant code:

```
import datetime
from datetime import date

class Page(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    url = models.URLField()
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    first_visit = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)
    last_visit = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)    

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.first_visit > datetime.date.today:
            self.first_visit = datetime.date.today
        if self.last_visit > datetime.date.today:
            self.last_visit = datetime.date.today

        super(Page, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

When I add a page from the admin it gives this error:

`Exception Value: unorderable types: datetime.date() > builtin_function_or_method()`

Any Idea? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`datetime.date.today` is a function callable, `datetime.date.today()` calls the function. I think you need to use `datetime.date.today()`.

Also it's not necessary to do what you have done to achieve last-modified timestamp in `save()` method, you can modify your `last_visit` field:

```
last_visit = models.DateField(auto_now=True, blank=True, null=True)
```

[django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now) is your friend.